# How to make Vegas Pro open AVI files

Tags: vegas-pro, avi

In using Vegas Pro 13 on a new Windows 10 computer, I find that I cannot open AVI files. It's not a codec issue; the file will not open at all because Vegas doesn't recognize it as a type of file it can open. I've used Vegas Pro for years and do not remember having this issue, but it has been five years since I got a new computer. [I've had trouble with the codecs in AVI files](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9917/vegas-pro-will-not-show-video-for-avi-with-mp4v-fourcc-codec), but they always opened.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that sometimes Vegas Pro's plugin that opens AVI files is corrupt or installed incorrectly (if this is the case, a reinstall may fix it).

There is a simple fix that involves replacing the DLL file that controls AVI files.

The file is called `aviplug.dll`. The file path will be similar to: `C:\Program Files\Sony\Vegas Pro 13.0\FileIO Plug-Ins\aviplug\`

- [The fixed dll can be found at Mediafire](https://www.mediafire.com/?1r1r3g5ut5quuub).
- [Here's a YouTube walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0h1rBtsqm4A).

Comment: dll missing now. Bummer.